# Creating an animation sequence with images in android (SlideShow)

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview, android-image

I am trying to set up a customized animated SlideShow of different images. I managd to set up  the animation for a single image using a customized view. Now I want to set up the slide show for all the images in my arraylist. So that the images will be displayed oina after each other .Right now I have one customized view do I need to make more views for each image? Any ideas?

Customized View:

`public class AnimationPhotoViewA extends ImageView
{
 @Overridepublic void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm)
{super.setImageBitmap(bm);image= bm;}`

ACTIVITY:

```
     public class PhotoSyncActivity extends Activity implements AnimationListener {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.photo_sync_screen);
    ArrayList<String> photoPaths = new ArrayList<String>();
    photoPaths = getAllPhotos(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            photoPaths);
    images = new Bitmap[photoPaths.size()];
    Log.v(ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE, "photo array!" + photoPaths);

    apa1 = (AnimationPhotoViewA) findViewById(R.id.animation_viewA);

             //START ANIMATION

    animationmove = PhotoAnimationProcess.moveOne(this,apa1,animationmove);

    File imgFile = new File(photoPaths.get(0));

    if (imgFile.exists())
    {
        images[0] = decodeFile(imgFile);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();


    // SET IMAGE IN THE VIEW
    apa1.setImageBitmap(resizedimage);

}
private void addPicture() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (animationmove) 
    {
    case move1:
        animationmove = PhotoAnimationProcess.moveOne(this, apa1, animationmove);
        break;
    case move2:
        addPicture();
        animationmove = PhotoAnimationProcess.moveTwo(this,apa1,animationmove);

        break;
    case move3:
        animationmove = PhotoAnimationProcess.moveThree(this,apa1,animationmove);
        break;
    case move4:
        animationmove = PhotoAnimationProcess.moveFour(this,apa1,animationmove);;
        break;
    case move5:
        animationmove = PhotoAnimationProcess.moveFive(this,apa1,animationmove);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    Log.v(ALARM_SERVICE, "Animation Type" + animation.toString());

}



public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [ImageSwitcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageSwitcher.html) widget. It seems to do exactly what you need. There is a lack of documentation for it so you may need to check the docs for its parents ViewSwitcher and ViewAnimator.

Basically ImageSwitcher does the following: when you supply a picture to it, the switcher plays an out animation with a picture it already has hiding it, and in the same time plays an in animation with the supplied picture showing it. Internally it cycles between two ImageViews.

One problem that you might encounter is that ImageSwitcher doesn't create its internal image views. You may either add a [ViewFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory.html) as shown in the [ApiDemos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ImageSwitcher1.html) or just add these image views in the layout file:

```
<ImageSwitcher ...>
    <ImageView ... />
    <ImageView ... />
</ImageSwitcher>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I need these images to run pro grammatically wit a specific animation with no focus on a certain image. I dont think the ImageSwitcher is going to help me

Comment: You're misunderstanding Darth Beleg's answer. The ImageSwitcher (or really, any of the switchers) gives you simple access to animations for swapping your images in and out nicely. You can populate those images programmatically with whatever Bitmaps you want, and save yourself the trouble of re-inventing this wheel (which is what you're doing above).